# How to install GCC without internet connection and what do I have to keep in mind when installing GCC?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I have 2 operating systems on my pc: windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. Windows 8.1 has internet connection, but Ubuntu does not. Is there a way I can download GCC for Ubuntu on my drive and then transfer and install it from there? what do I have to keep in mind when installing?

Note: I have never installoed a program on Ubuntu before!!

Specs:
ubuntu 13.10 32bit
windows 8.1 64bit

After trying the awnser I got this error:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/131390508@N06/16405946079/

Comment: because my ubuntu does not connect with my wireless 3g modum

Comment: you don't get it, I have a 3g modum which does not come with UTP. There is no linux or mac support AT ALL(thank you alcatel). so I have to download files to my windows drive and then transfer them

Comment: yeah but I thought that you ment that I had to put it in there... anyway There is no way to get internet because that's the only thing I have. I can't buy stuff just to be able to download free software right? and if there is another way it would be better in my case

Answer (score 0):

To get the most out of your machine you should consider troubleshooting your internet connection first. As for GCC, try installing `build-essential` from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/build-essential/download). It includes GCC and its dependencies.

Comment: How should I install it?

Comment: After downloading, install by running  `sudo dpkg -i build-essential_11.7_i386.deb`

Comment: I got an error can you take a look at it?

Comment: The `build-essential` package is a metapackage - it doesn't actually contain any of the software (look at its size - only a few kB). I don't see how this is going to help you.

Comment: That's what I thought but I also thought that it might just have been a few commands to execute the gcc. what do I have to do Instead?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from not having an internet connection, you will have to face the issue that Ubuntu 13.10 is an end-of-life (EOL) release and is no longer supported.

In general, the most reliable way to identify and download the `gcc` package *along with its missing dependencies* from a system with no internet connection is probably to use

```
apt-get install --print-uris gcc
```

or perhaps better

```
apt-get install --print-uris build-essential
```

on the Ubuntu machine, and then use the listed URLs to download the packages on your internet-connected computer. **However because you are using an EOL release the URLs will no longer be valid in this case**.

Comment: There are none that say ubuntu 13.10 on the website you gave me??

Comment: The Saucy old-releases archive is at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/ however I have removed that from the "answer" since I don't actually know how (or if it's possible) to translate the apt-get URIs into a suitable form.

Comment: so this might not even be possibile?