# Do I have GCC somewhere? (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS). Sudo apt-get is not an option (no driver for ethernet)

Tags: gcc

I can't sudo apt-get because I need an ethernet driver.  I can't install the driver because I apparently don't have gcc.

"cat /proc/version" tells me that I have gcc version 9.3.0 but how do I use this gcc? When I try to dpkg debians I am told that I am missing gcc.  I can't run 'make'.  Can anyone please help me out of this pickle?

Comment: AFAIK `/proc/version` just tells you what version of gcc was used to build the kernel - it does not indicate that the gcc package is currently installed. You will probably need to use one of the methods described here: [How to install GCC without internet connection and what do I have to keep in mind when installing GCC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587804/how-to-install-gcc-without-internet-connection-and-what-do-i-have-to-keep-in-min)

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer includes a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can test your hardware before installing, avoiding a pickle like this. Installing GCC without a network connection can be tedious and frustrating. It might be much easier to borrow (or purchase) a cheap USB-to-Ethernet dongle.

Comment: You can always connect with a USB cable to a phone and install everything you like.